# Unable to Apply REPLICATION SLAVE privilege on AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, mysql-error-1064

i am trying to setup a master & slave replication in rds instance  .
I am using the following code

```
CREATE USER fivetran@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
GRANT SELECT, REPLICATION CLIENT, REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO fivetran@'%';
```

how ever i am getting

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'%' (using password: YES) .

What should i do to fix the issue ?

my mysql version is `5.5.46` , as per aws documents its mentioned as  REPLICATION SLAVE (only for Amazon RDS MySQL versions 5.6, 5.7 and 8.0, Amazon RDS MariaDB) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.MasterAccounts.html

Can someone help me in this issue ?

Comment: You created a user called `fivetran`  now you are using `user`??

Comment: its not clear which statement is throwing the error... is it the CREATE USER statement, or the GRANT statement? or did those execute successfully, and the error is from some other statement? The error message doesn't appear to be related to any of the statements shown in the question, It just looks like there's an attempt to connect to the database (as `user@'%'`) and that attempt is unsuccessful (connection denied by the MySQL server) because the wrong password is being supplied, or possibly the user `user@'%'` isn't defined, or ...

Comment: GRANT SELECT, REPLICATION CLIENT, REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO fivetran@'%'; this statement is throwing the error.